# Is likelihood in the background of both, anova and AIC?

Tags: regression, anova, aic, likelihood, deviance

Trying to compare different statistical tests, in particular `anova(model,test="Chisq")` and AIC, I have read the nice discussion under [Logistic regression: anova chi-square test vs. significance of coefficients (anova() vs summary() in R)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59879/logistic-regression-anova-chi-square-test-vs-significance-of-coefficients-ano)

However, it raised for me the question whether likelihood is in the background of both, AIC and the deviance results produced by an ANOVA (which would make these tests too similar to be done both in practice), since - as pointed out under the above link - test="Chisq" is the same as test="LRT", where LRT stands for likelihood ratio test.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188076/is-anova-relying-on-the-method-of-moments-and-not-on-the-maximum-likelihood