# What exactly do Anova sums of squares represent in lmer models?

Tags: anova, lme4-nlme, likelihood-ratio, f-test, sums-of-squares

In a `lme4::lmer` model, the `anova` function returns an sequential analysis of variance table.
As explained on page 34 of http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf the numerator sum of squares for each F statistic is calculated by the following:
$$
\mathit{SS}_i = \hat{\beta}^\top \mathbf{R}_i^\top \mathbf{R}_i \hat{\beta},
$$
where $\mathbf{R}_i^T$ is obtained from decompositions of matrices in the likelihood function, and the some of the key `lme4` code that does this calculation can be found at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/lmer.R#L590 for example.

Here's an example:

```r
> library(lme4)
> M <- lmer(Reaction ~ factor(Days) + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
> anova(M)
Analysis of Variance Table
             npar Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
factor(Days)    9 166235   18471  18.703
```

My question is what the denominator sums of squares, i.e. with the value 166235 above represents?

To be clearer about what exactly I am asking, consider the anova in a non-mixed-effects normal linear model, e.g. an `lm` model. There, what the numerator sums of squares represents is very clear: it represents the difference in the residual sums of squares of two nested models (see, for example, Maxwell, Delaney, & Kelley (2018) *Designing Experiments and Analyzing Data: A Model Comparison Perspective* for elaboration), which is also equivalent in this example to the total sums of squares minus the residual sums of squares. For example,

```r
> M1 <- lm(Reaction ~ factor(Days), data = sleepstudy)
> anova(M1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Reaction
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
factor(Days)   9 166235 18470.6  7.8164 1.317e-09 ***
Residuals    170 401719  2363.1                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> M0 <- update(M, . ~ . - factor(Days))
> sum(M0$residuals^2) - sum(M$residuals^2)
[1] 166235.1
```

(While the values of the relevant sums of squares in the `lm` and the `lmer` model in these examples are the same, that will not necessarily be the case).

In the `lmer` model, the Anova numerator sums of squares don't represent the difference of the residual sums of squares of the two relevant nested models. For example,

```r
> M <- lmer(Reaction ~ factor(Days) + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
> M3 <- update(M, . ~ . - factor(Days))
> sum(residuals(M3)^2) - sum(residuals(M)^2)
[1] 169535.2
```

So what exactly does $\mathit{SS}_i = \hat{\beta}^\top \mathbf{R}_i^\top \mathbf{R}_i \hat{\beta}$ represent, and how does it relate to the numerator sum of squares in normal linear models? Is there, for example, a way of writing the numerator sums of squares in normal linear models in an analogous matrix way to $\mathit{SS}_i = \hat{\beta}^\top \mathbf{R}_i^\top \mathbf{R}_i \hat{\beta}$?

More generally, what does the F statistic in a `lmer` model Anova represent? Again, in a non-mixed-effect normal linear model, the F statistic is transformation the likelihood ratio of the two nested models, specifically.
$$
\frac{L_1}{L_0} = \left[ F \frac{\mathit{df}_0 - \mathit{df}_1}{\mathit{df_1}} + 1 \right]^{n/2}
$$
For example,

```r
> f <- anova(M1)[1,4]
> n <- nrow(sleepstudy)
> (n/2) * log(f * (M0$df.residual - M1$df.residual)/M1$df.residual + 1)
[1] 31.16589
> logLik(M1)-logLik(M0)
'log Lik.' 31.16589 (df=11)
```

But in a `lmer` model, it is not as simple as that:

```r
> f <- anova(M)[1,4]
> n <- nrow(sleepstudy)
> (n/2) * log(f * (df.residual(M0) - df.residual(M1))/df.residual(M1) + 1)
[1] 61.93858
> logLik(M)-logLik(M3)
'log Lik.' 87.41698 (df=12)
```

In general it seems that the meaning of sums of squares and F statistics etc in normal linear models does not carry over to linear mixed effects model. But presumably there is still some important relationship between the concepts in these different contexts? But I am just not sure exactly what that is, and this question is an attempt to gain more clarity and insight.

For the record, this question [What does the anova() command do with a lmer model object?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71914/what-does-the-anova-command-do-with-a-lmer-model-object) is relevant and I found it and the accepted answer to be very useful. However, I do not think my question now is a duplicate, nor is the answer to that question an answer to what $\mathit{SS}_i = \hat{\beta}^\top \mathbf{R}_i^\top \mathbf{R}_i \hat{\beta}$ means and how it relates to numerator sums of squares in normal linear models.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer this question based on what I understand from the article Bates et al. (2015), which is the same document as the lmer vignette cited in the question. The goal here is to better understand what the sum of squares for the fixed effect $i$ means, which is given by:
$$
\mathit{SS}_i = \hat{\beta}^\top \boldsymbol{R}_i^\top \boldsymbol{R}_i \hat{\beta}
$$

First of all, as it is stated in page 33 of the paper, $\boldsymbol{R}_i$ contain the rows of $\boldsymbol{R}_X$ associated with the $i$th fixed-effects term. The matrix $\boldsymbol{R}_X$ first appears in Eq. 18, on page 14. It is part of the Cholesky decomposition of the system matrix that appears in Eq. 17. This later matrix comes from the minimization of the penalized weighted residual sum-of-squares (Eq. 14), when the parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ (the covariance parameter vector, associated with the random effects) are fixed.

Eq. 18 (and, also, Eq. 50) indicates how the matrix $\boldsymbol{R}_X$ is computed:
$$
\boldsymbol{R}_X^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X = \boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{X} - \boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}
$$

We will see later in this answer how this matrix $\boldsymbol{R}_X$ can be related to the sum of squares associated with the fixed effects. We will discuss later the meaning of the other two matrices ($\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}$ that appear in the equation above.

Before getting to that, let us first consider a linear fixed-effects model, in which the response vector $\mathcal{Y}$ is normally distributed and whose mean value has a linear dependence on the fixed effects, represented by the $p$-dimensional coefficient vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}$:
$$
\mathcal{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2)
$$

Here, $\boldsymbol{X}$ is the $n\times p$ model matrix ($n$ is the number of observations, or the length of $\mathcal{Y}$). Note that this is similar to Eq. 1 of the paper, but I am considering $\boldsymbol{o}$ (the vector of known prior offset terms) to be equal to zero and $\boldsymbol{W}$ (the diagonal matrix of known prior weights) to be equal to the identity matrix, for sake of simplicity.

Let us make things concrete with an example in R. The code below prepares the data that will be used to fit both fixed-effects and mixed-effects models:

```r
### number of levels of fixed effect x
p <- 2
### number of groups
q <- 4
### number of repetitions per level of x and per group
n <- 2
### Values for x
x <- rep(c(-1, 1), each = q * n)
### Groups
g <- gl(q, n, n * p * q)
### Fixed effects
fe.i <- 0.1
fe.x <- 0.5
### Random effects
set.seed(12345678)
re.i <- rnorm(q)
re.i <- 0.1 *(re.i - mean(re.i)) / sd(re.i)
re.x <- rnorm(q)
re.x <- 0.2 *(re.x - mean(re.x)) / sd(re.x)
### Noise
noise <- rnorm(n * p * q, sd = 0.3)
### Dependent variable
y <- fe.i + fe.x * x + re.i [g] + re.x [g] * x + noise
### Data frame
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, g = g)
```

Note that the factor `x` is continuous and was chosen such that there is no interaction between the fixed effects intercept and slope.

The fixed-effects linear model described above is fitted, in R, as follows:

```r
m1 <- lm(y ~ x, dat)
```

The fitted coefficients $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ can be extracted as:

```r
m1.beta <- coefficients(m1)
```

whose values are:

```r
> m1.beta
(Intercept)           x
  0.1492887   0.4151967
```

The model matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$ can be composed as:

```r
X.m1 <- cbind(rep(1, n * p * q), x)
```

Assuming that:
$$
\boldsymbol{y}_{\mathrm{obs}} = \boldsymbol{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ is the vector of residuals with mean equal to zero and standard deviation $\sigma$, the total sum of squares $\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{total}$ can be related to the sum of squares due to the fixed coefficients $\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{fixef}$ and to the sum squares of the residuals $\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{resid}$:
$$
\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{total} = \mathit{SS}_\mathrm{fixef} + \mathit{SS}_\mathrm{resid}
$$
where:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{total} &= \boldsymbol{y}_{\mathrm{obs}}^\top\boldsymbol{y}_{\mathrm{obs}}\\
\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{fixef} &= \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\\
\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{resid} &= \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}^\top\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}
\end{align}
$$

These values can be computed as follows:

```r
SS.fixef <- t(m1.beta) %*% t(X.m1) %*% X.m1 * m1.beta
SS.m1.resid <- sum(residuals(m1) ^ 2)
```

and are visualized with the following code:

```r
> cat(sprintf("SS.fixef: %f (intercept), %f (slope)\nSS.resid: %f\n",
+            SS.fixef[1], SS.fixef[2], SS.m1.resid))
SS.fixef: 0.356594 (intercept), 2.758212 (slope)
SS.resid: 2.141890
```

Note that, when computing `SS.fixef`, the last multiplication is scalar (`*`) instead of matrix (`%*%`), such that the sums of squares for both intercept and slope are computed separately.

The total sum of squares is computed as follows:

```r
SS.total <- t(dat$y) %*% dat$y
```

and we can verify that the equation $\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{total} = \mathit{SS}_\mathrm{fixef} + \mathit{SS}_\mathrm{resid}$ holds:

```r
> cat(sprintf("SS.total: %f\nSS.fixef + SS.resid: %f\n",
+             SS.total, sum(SS.fixef) + SS.resid))
SS.total: 5.256697
SS.fixef + SS.m1.resid: 5.256697
```

The values for the sums of squares for the slope (dependent on variable `x`) and for the residuals, which are respectively 2.75821 and 2.1419, are the identical to the ones that are obtained by the call of the `anova` function on model `m1`:

```r
> anova(m1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)
x          1 2.7582 2.75821  18.029 0.0008145 ***
Residuals 14 2.1419 0.15299
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Let us now investigate the mixed-effects model and how it deals with the same data. According to Bates al. (2015), the conditional distribution of $\mathcal{Y}$ given $\mathcal{B} = \boldsymbol{b}$ has the form:
$$
(\mathcal{Y}|\mathcal{B} = \boldsymbol{b}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{Z}\boldsymbol{b}, \sigma^2)
$$
where $\boldsymbol{Z}$ is the $n \times q$ model matrix for the $q$-dimensional vector-valued random-effects variable, $\mathcal{B}$, whose value is fixed at $\boldsymbol{b}$. The unconditional distribution of $\mathcal{B}$ is also multivariate normal with mean zero and a $q \times q$ variance-covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. Again, the matrix of weights $\boldsymbol{W}$ is ignored here for the sake of simplicity.

Note that in the data defined above (included in the data frame `dat`), there is a grouping factor `g`, which has four levels. For each one of these levels, there are two measurements for $x = -1$ and another two measurements for $x = 1$. The data has been generated such that random effects on both intercept (with size `re.i`) and slope (with size `re.x`) are induced. With 16 observations in total, it is possible to fit a model containing random effects for both intercept and slope, avoiding singularities in the fit.

This is a graphical representation of the data:

```r
png(file = "data.png", width = 500, height = 470)
par(mar = c (5, 4, 0.1, 0.1))
cols <- c("red", "blue", "gold", "green4")
plot(dat$y, las = 1, pch = 19, col = cols[dat$g],
     ylab = "Y", cex = 1.5, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = seq (1, nrow (dat)))
legend("topleft", ins = 0.05, col = cols, pch = 19,
       legend = sapply (seq (1, q), function (x) sprintf ("group %d", x)))
dummy <- dev.off()
```

[image: data representation]

The horizontal axis is just the row index of data frame `dat`. The value of $x$ for the first 8 points is $-1$ and the value of $x$ for the last 8 points is $1$.

We fit a mixed-effects model with two fixed factors (for intercept and slope) and with two random factors, specified by the formula element `(x || g)`, which is equivalent to `(1 | g) + (0 + x | g)` (i.e., we do not consider a correlation between random effects for intercept and slope):

```r
library(lme4)
m2 <- lmer(y ~ x + (x || g), dat)
```

The fitted fixed coefficients $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ can be extracted from the `m2` object with this code:

```r
m2.beta <- fixef(m2)
```

They are identical to the coefficients fitted to the fixed-effects model `m1`:

```r
> cat(sprintf("FE model: intercept = %f, slope = %f\nME model: intercept = %f, slope = %f\n",
+            m1.beta[1], m1.beta[2], m2.beta[1], m2.beta[2]))
FE model: intercept = 0.149289, slope = 0.415197
ME model: intercept = 0.149289, slope = 0.415197
```

The model matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$ for `m2` can be extracted with the following code:

```r
X.m2 <- getME(m2, "X")
XtX <- t(X.m2) %*% X.m2
```

It is identical to the model matrix for `m1`:

```r
> X.m1
         x
 [1,] 1 -1
 [2,] 1 -1
 [3,] 1 -1
 [4,] 1 -1
 [5,] 1 -1
 [6,] 1 -1
 [7,] 1 -1
 [8,] 1 -1
 [9,] 1  1
[10,] 1  1
[11,] 1  1
[12,] 1  1
[13,] 1  1
[14,] 1  1
[15,] 1  1
[16,] 1  1
> X.m2
   (Intercept)  x
1            1 -1
2            1 -1
3            1 -1
4            1 -1
5            1 -1
6            1 -1
7            1 -1
8            1 -1
9            1  1
10           1  1
11           1  1
12           1  1
13           1  1
14           1  1
15           1  1
16           1  1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1
attr(,"msgScaleX")
character(0)
```

We can easily see that the values of $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$
are the same for `m1` and `m2`:

```r
> t(m1.beta) %*% t(X.m1) %*% X.m1 %*% m1.beta
         [,1]
[1,] 3.114806
> t(m2.beta) %*% XtX %*% m2.beta
         [,1]
[1,] 3.114806
```

Remember that this was the value for the sum of squares associated with the fixed factors in the fixed-effects models. This is not the case for the mixed-effects model and **we reach now the important point of this answer**. As we have seen at the beginning of my text, $\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}$ is the sum of two terms (ignoring the $\boldsymbol{W}$ matrix, for the sake of simplicity):
$$
\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X} = \boldsymbol{R}_X^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X + \boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}
$$

Pre-multiplying by $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top$ and post-multiplying by $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ both sides of the equation above:
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{X}^\top\boldsymbol{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} + \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}
$$
gives us an expression for the sums of squares that are related to fixed coefficients of the model. The right-hand side is the sum of squares of the fixed-effects model fitted to the same data. We see that this value is partitioned into two terms:

1. the term $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ that is related to the fixed-effects coefficients per se,
2. and the term $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ that appears because we are fitting a mixed-effects linear model to the data. Its value depends on the model matrix for the random effects $\boldsymbol{Z}$ and on the values of the parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ of the variance-covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_\boldsymbol{\theta}$. It is computed during the algebraic phase of the penalized least squares algorithm (Eq. 49).

This is why one should only consider the term $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ when computing the $F$ statistics for testing the fixed effects. One further indication that this must the case comes from the fact that the covariance matrix of the fixed-effects coefficients is given by (Eq. 54 of Bates et al. 2015):
$$
\mathrm{Var}_{\boldsymbol{\theta}, \sigma}(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}) = \sigma^2 \boldsymbol{R}_X^{-1} (\boldsymbol{R}_X^\top)^{-1}
$$
and depends only on $\boldsymbol{R}_X$, besides $\sigma$.

The total sum of squares for the mixed-effects model can then be partitioned into four terms:
$$
\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{total} = \mathit{SS}_{RX} + \mathit{SS}_{RZX} + \mathit{SS}_\mathrm{ranef} + \mathit{SS}_\mathrm{resid}
$$
where:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathit{SS}_{RX} &= \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X^\top\boldsymbol{R}_X\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\\
\mathit{SS}_{RZX} &= \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}^\top\boldsymbol{R}_{ZX}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\\
\end{align}
$$

The term $\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{resid}$ is only related to the residuals error (the value of $\sigma$) and the term $\mathit{SS}_\mathrm{ranef}$ is only related to the random effects (the values in the variance-covariance matrix of the random effects $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_\boldsymbol{\theta}$).

In our example, this is how these values are computed:

```r
RX <- getME(m2, "RX")
RZX <- getME(m2, "RZX")
RXtRX <- t(RX) %*% RX
RZXtRZX <- t(RZX) %*% RZX
SS.RX <- t(m2.beta) %*% RXtRX * m2.beta
SS.RZX <- t(m2.beta) %*% RZXtRZX %*% m2.beta
SS.m2.resid <- sum((dat$y - predict(m2)) ^ 2)
SS.ranef <- sum((dat$y - predict(m2, re.form=NA)) ^ 2) - SS.m2.resid
```

As we did previously, the last multiplication in the computation of `SS.RX` is scalar (`*`) instead of matrix (`%*%`), such that we can get the separated sums of squares for the intercept and the slope (this is another way of computing $\mathit{SS}_i$ with $\boldsymbol{R}_i$, as stated at the beginning of this answer).

We can verify that all terms sum up to the value of the total sum of squares ($\mathit{SS}_{\mathrm{total}}$):

```r
> cat(sprintf("SS.RX: intercept = %f, slope = %f\nSS.RZ: %f\nSS.ranef: %f\nSS.m2.resid: %f\n\nSS.RX + SS.RZ + SS.ranef + SS.m2.resid: %f\nSS.total: %f\n",
+             SS.RX[1], SS.RX[2], SS.RZX, SS.ranef, SS.m2.resid,
+             sum(SS.RX) + SS.RZX + SS.ranef + SS.m2.resid,
+             SS.total))
SS.RX: intercept = 0.070573, slope = 2.181704
SS.RZ: 0.862529
SS.ranef: 1.270335
SS.m2.resid: 0.871556

SS.RX + SS.RZ + SS.ranef + SS.m2.resid: 5.256697
SS.total: 5.256697
```

As it should be, the value for the sum of squares for the fixed-effect slope (`SS.RX[2]`) is exactly the same as the value that appears when `anova` is invoked for `m2`:

```r
> anova(m2)
Analysis of Variance Table
  npar Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
x    1 2.1817  2.1817  27.452
```

So to summarize, the value of the sum of squares associated with the coefficients of a mixed-effects model is somehow related to the sum of squares associated with the coefficients of the equivalent fixed-effects model fitted to the same data, in the sense that the former is a part of the later. This can be visualized in the figure below, where the width of the rectangles are proportional to the respective sums of squares (see Appendix for the code that generates part of this figure).

[image]

In this figure, the pink and the cyan rectangles correspond to the sums of squares that are used to compute the $F$ statistics that appear in the ANOVA tables, for both fixed-effects and mixed-effects models.

**References**

Bates D, Mächler M, Bolker B, Walker S (2015) Fitting linear mixed-effects models using lme4. J Stat Softw 67(1). DOI: [10.18637/jss.v067.i01](http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v067.i01).

**Appendix**

This is the code for generating part of the last figure. The generated SVG file was further edited in Inkscape for adding the labels.

```r
svg(file = "ss.svg", width = 7, height = 4)
plot(NA, NA, type = "n", bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
     xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim = c(0, SS.total), ylim = c(0, 2.5))
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
o <- 0
for (s in c (SS.fixef[1], SS.fixef[2], SS.m1.resid)) {
    polygon(o + x * s, y + 1.5)
    o <- o + s
}
o <- 0
for (s in c (SS.RX[1], SS.RX[2], SS.RZX, SS.ranef, SS.m2.resid)) {
    polygon(o + x * s, y)
    o <- o + s
}
dummy <- dev.off()
```